# How to display assigned group with list_display in Django admin?

Tags: python, django

How can I display assigned group to users with `list_display` in admin.py?

```
class usr_fields(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class usr_fields(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Meta:
        model = User

    list_display = ('get_groups')

    def get_groups(self, obj):
        return obj.groups.values_list('name',flat=True)

    get_groups.short_description = 'Groups'
```

Comment: whats returns on this?

Comment: It doesn't return anything what I can see.

Comment: I added the Meta subclass and assigned User to the variable model. But I get the error: `NameError: name 'User' is not defined`

Comment: you need import the User, from from django.contrib.auth.models import User

Comment: Yes, I tried that also after I got the error. Then the error disappears and no extra field is returned. Can I print something out on the screen to test if some of it works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92136/discussion-between-paulo-pessoa-and-qao).

Answer (score 0):

It can be like this: [Extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin


class usr_fields(UserAdmin):
    list_display = ("username", "email", "group_name", "first_name", "last_name", "is_staff")

    def group_name(self, obj):
        return obj.groups.values_list('name',flat=True).get()

    group_name.short_description = 'group'

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```